# .dll from a .net 7 project in .net 3.1 project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I generated a dll from a .net 7 project and added the dll to a .net 3.1 project, but I can't compile the project after adding the dll because the following error occurs

> error CS1705: Assembly '[project]' with identity '[project],
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses
> 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neu tral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than
> referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime,
> Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, Pub licKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Compiling the .net 3.1 project with the dll (.net 7) is what I need. What do I have to do? Update system.runtime?

Comment: If your project has no "special" dependencies like ASP NET Core etc. you can try to compile your net 7 as .NET Standard 2.0 and you can consume it in 3.1. Just change your `TargetFramework` from `net7.0` to `netstandard2.0` and try it out.

Answer (score 3):

They are not compatible with each other.

Short answer: No.

Low cost: upgrade your old project.